# Как отправить документ через бот Telegram?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

При таком коде выходит ошибка:

```
doc = open('https://magnit.ru/upload/iblock/5cc/5cc79c53d76dfe781f69ff330467d47d.pdf', 'rb')
token_bot.send_document(message.chat.id, doc)
```

Такой код работает, но отправляет файл без пдф:

```
token_bot.send_document(message.chat.id, requests.get("https://magnit.ru/upload/iblock/5cc/5cc79c53d76dfe781f69ff330467d47d.pdf").content)
```

Comment: Укажите **в вопросе**, какая "выходит ошибка"

Comment: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'https://magnit.ru/upload/iblock/5cc/5cc79c53d76dfe781f69ff330467d47d.pdf'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Телеграм поддерживает отправку файлов по url, попробуйте просто

```py
token_bot.send_document(message.chat.id, 'https://magnit.ru/upload/iblock/5cc/5cc79c53d76dfe781f69ff330467d47d.pdf')
```

> pass an HTTP URL as a String for Telegram to get a file from the
> Internet
>
> [Telegram Docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument)

Comment: Спасибо, жаль нельзя больше 20 мб загружать.